# Installing SAGA GIS 2.1

Tags: ubuntu, saga, sextante-qgis-plugin

I am using QGIS 1.9 master with Ubuntu 13.04. I tried to use the SAGA hydrology tools in sextante today and it said they did not appeared to be installed. I checked and sure enough SAGA was indeed installed.

I did some searching and found out I need to update SAGA to version 2.1. I added the unofficial ppa (ppa:johanvdw/saga-gis) and ran `sudo apt-get update` and tried to install. I get a message telling me it is already installed. So I uninstalled 2.0.8 and tried again. It just reinstalled 2.0.8. I tried targeting the install `sudo apt-get install -t saga-gis saga`. it told me there was no saga-gis. I opened the synaptic package handler to choose the packages manually and nothing shows up their either. However, when I look at the software and updates section I can clearly see the added repository and according to the launchpad site their is a raring version. Here is a picture showing synaptic.[image] 
Any ideas??

Comment: As I haven't installed SAGA, I can't comment on your issue. I can only suggest that you can try installing the same from source using these [instructions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/saga-gis/wiki/Compiling%20SAGA%20on%20Linux)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following commands from a command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:johanvdw/saga-gis
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install saga
```

The problem may be that synaptic has not updated it sources because the signing key was not imported. This should be the most easy way to fix that error.

[update]
It seems the wxwidgets package for raring was uploaded but not build for some reason. This is now fixed. You should be able to install saga on raring.

Comment: I had done all of that and still nothing. It's like the files from the ppa are not being added to the list. I just realized you are the person who runs the PPA, Hello :)

Comment: PPA is fixed, install should work fine now.

Comment: Thank you so much! I turned on my software updater today and everything installed.