# SAGA installation in QGIS 2.8 on debian linux

Tags: qgis, installation, saga, qgis-processing, debian

I install QGIS 2.8 in debian (linux) through nightly jessie (qgis testing) and I see that SAGA is not in processing toolbox, so I install saga gis software but still it doesn't appear in processing.

How do I run SAGA in processing toolbox?

UPDATE:

This problem is resolved through the line commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:johanvdw/saga-gis

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install saga
```

But in my case (Debian Jessie) instead of `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:johanvdw/saga-gis` I went to https://launchpad.net/~johanvdw/+archive/ubuntu/saga-gis and in Technical details about this PPA I choose Trusty version, copy the lines and paste in sources.list. It works!!!

---

I try the commands in terminal but it didn't work and I get this error (I suppose it is not correct):

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit http://ftp.pt.debian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://ftp.pt.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease                          
Hit http://ftp.pt.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie InRelease                                  
Get:1 http://ftp.pt.debian.org jessie/main Sources/DiffIndex [7,876 B]         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie InRelease                                  
Get:2 http://qgis.org sid InRelease [3,341 B]                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie InRelease                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie InRelease                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie InRelease                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release.gpg                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release.gpg                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release.gpg                         
Get:3 http://ftp.pt.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [7,876 B]
Get:4 http://ftp.pt.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [7,876 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release.gpg   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release.gpg   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release.gpg   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release.gpg   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release                              
Hit http://ftp.pt.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources                       
Ign http://qgis.org sid InRelease                                              
Hit http://ftp.pt.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages                
Hit http://ftp.pt.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en                
Hit http://ftp.pt.debian.org jessie-backports/main Sources                     
Hit http://ftp.pt.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release                                    
Hit http://ftp.pt.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release                                    
Ign http://qgis.org sid/main Sources/DiffIndex                        
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en     
Ign http://qgis.org sid/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                 
Hit http://qgis.org sid/main amd64 Packages                                    
Ign http://qgis.org sid/main Translation-en_US                                 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://qgis.org sid/main Translation-en                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://qgis.org sid/main Sources                                           
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main Translation-en                        
Fetched 27.0 kB in 10s (2,690 B/s)                                             
W: GPG error: http://qgis.org sid InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 030561BEDD45F6C3
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/johanvdw/saga-gis/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/otb/orfeotoolbox-nightly/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/otb/orfeotoolbox-stable/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/otb/orfeotoolbox-stable-ubuntugis/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: In Processing -> Options -> Data Provider, have you activated SAGA?

Comment: Yes, I activate SAGA in processing options. However, it still down't appear in processing toolbox. I have SAGA installed and I test with saga_cmd command. It works. But with processing it doesn't.

Comment: Did you switch to the advanced view? It just looks like there is no SAGA in the simplified view. (Dropbox at the bottom of the toolbox.)

Comment: Check that the box SAGA 2.0.8 compatibility is not checked.

Comment: I switch to the advanced view but there isn't SAGA there. The SAGA 2.0.8 compatibility box isn't in the processing options. There are only these options for SAGA: Activate (check on), Enable SAGA Import/Export optimizations, Log console output, Log execution commands. It is strange for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but, looking on the web, I found a solution.
Simply, I installed SAGA from other repository ([Installing SAGA GIS 2.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70283/installing-saga-gis-2-1)).

Try the following commands from a command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:johanvdw/saga-gis

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install saga
```

I hope it works.

Comment: Can confirm the problem (my Debian Linux still uses v2.1.2, which is not recognized anymore by QGIS). Installing the debs from this link creates a new Processing-Provider entry for SAGA 2.1.4

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who would like to have SAGA 2.1.4 in Jessie:
After jessie is released I will try to add it to backports.
In the mean time, I recommend using the packages from unstable. These will work with jessie without needing to recompile.
You will need to install both libsaga and saga.

https://packages.debian.org/nl/sid/saga
https://packages.debian.org/nl/sid/libsaga